# Get numbering of nested "orderedlist" using xref or another element in docbook

Tags: xslt, docbook

I would like to **use docbook to write a contract-style document** and I would like to create links in this document using xref or another element. I can make links to chapters, sections or other elements as shown below to demonstrate that it works. I'm unable to make a sophisicated **links with auto-generated content (much like current xref) to nested "orderedlist".**

What I need:

I have a nested orderedlist in docbook with numeration in arabic, then loweralpha and then lowerroman:

```
1. Aaa1
  a) Bbb1
    i) Ccc1
    ii) Ccc2 - this element has an ID
```

When pointing xref to the mentioned element via id, xref generates only "ii" - the last number. Not the whole "path" or "tree" to the given element.

I need to make a link using xref that auto-generates link content to look like
**1. a) ii**

or
**"Level1: 1, Level2: b, Level3: ii"**

Eventually if the orderedlist was in a chapter 3 and section 3.5, the output of xref would be something like:
**Chapter 3, Section 3.5, 3.b.ii**

Or similar to this, if the orderedlist does have just two levels, not three:
**Chapter 3, Section 3.5, 3.b**

This is a current test case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">

    <chapter xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xml:id="chapter_element">

        <title>Chapter title</title>

        <orderedlist numeration="arabic">
            <listitem>
                Aaa1
                <orderedlist numeration="loweralpha">
                    <listitem>Bbb1</listitem>
                    <listitem>
                        Bbb2
                        <orderedlist numeration="lowerroman">
                            <listitem>Ccc1</listitem>
                            <listitem xml:id="item_element">Ccc2</listitem>
                        </orderedlist>
                    </listitem>
                </orderedlist>
            </listitem>
        </orderedlist>


        <section>
            <title>Section1 title</title>
            <para>
                Lorem ipsum
            </para>
        </section>

        <section xml:id="section_element">
            <title>Section2 title</title>
            <para>
                Dolor si amet
            </para>
        </section>


        <para>
            Chapter: <xref linkend="chapter_element" xrefstyle="template:the chapter numbered %n"/>
        </para>

        <para>
            Chapter: <xref linkend="chapter_element" xrefstyle="select: labelnumber quotedtitle"/>
        </para>


        <para>
            Section: <xref linkend="section_element" xrefstyle="template:the section numbered %n"/>
        </para>

        <para>
            Section: <xref linkend="section_element" xrefstyle="select: labelnumber quotedtitle"/>
        </para>


        <para>
            ListItem: <xref linkend="item_element" xrefstyle="template:the item numbered %n"/>
        </para>

        <para>
            ListItem: <xref linkend="item_element" xrefstyle="select: labelnumber quotedtitle"/>
        </para>

    </chapter>

</book>
```

The output is:

```
Chapter: the chapter numbered 1
Chapter: 1: „Chapter title“
Section: the section numbered 1.2
Section: 1.2: „Section2 title“
ListItem: ii
ListItem: ii
```

The text that xref generates is good enough for chapter and section. However as you see at the end of this example, the **xref returns only the last listitem** number ("ii" in lowerroman). What I need - customize xref somehow to return the whole path, example: "Level1: 1, Level2: b), Level3: ii"

I've read some articles about customizing xref but was not able to make it work with orderedlists, only with chapter and section elements.

I'm not an expert in XSLT, so anything that will move me forward or any working example will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

**Update1**: Rendered using unmodified docbook5 XLS files on windows using xsltproc.exe

```
xsltproc.exe --xinclude C:/path/to/docbook5/xsl/xhtml/docbook.xsl source/xref-test.xml > dist/html-flat/xref-test.html
```

It seems that using this XSLT the two section link contents does not get the section number, only the title. Which mean that the XSLT I'm using must be slightly modified. However chapter link contents and ListItem contents were rendered as shown. If you want to reproduce the problem, just render the XML above using docbook5/xsl/xhtml/docbook.xsl as shown above. Chapter link contents are OK, I don't mind at the moment about section links but what I'd like to have is get the numbering of nested orderedlists.

Comment: Can you include your stylesheet (or the relevant parts of it necessary to reproduce the problem?)

Comment: Section number output "1.2" was rendered after setting
`<xsl:param name="section.autolabel" select="'1'"/>`
`<xsl:param name="section.label.includes.component.label" select="'1'"/>`
`<xsl:param name="section.autolabel.max.depth" select="'2'"/>`
There does not seem to be any functionality to track inheritance like "section.level" for orderedlist unfortunately